# Helgrind for Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, valgrind

> Helgrind is a Valgrind tool for
>   detecting synchronisation errors in C,
>   C++ and Fortran programs that use the
>   POSIX pthreads threading primitives.

Anyone knows an equivalent tool for windows? After googling a bit I haven't found anything...

Comment: Well, its tough to get Valgrind for Windows. The best I have heard is a WINE based technique.

Comment: I don't want to use Valgrind, I want something similar but native for windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the people that eventually should land there: I've found that: [Intel thread checker](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-thread-checker/):  should be pretty similar to Hellgrind.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing of heard of in this area is [CHESS](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/chess/), from Microsoft Research.  Never used it though.  No idea if its equivalent to Helgrind in any meaningful way.

Comment: CHESS is for Heisenbugs: bugs that disappear when you use a debugger or insert trace prints (that modify the interleaving of the threads in such a way that the bugs doesn't reproduce).
Helgrind is a different beast: it is a VM that traces the memory accesses: if it finds that two threads write on the same memory location (or one read and one write, you get the idea) without proper syncronization, then it report to you the fact, along the number lines of the offending code.