# Controlled application shut-down strategy

Tags: c++, shutdown, application-shutdown, shutdown-hook

Our (Windows native C++) app is composed of threaded objects and managers.  It is pretty well written, with a design that sees Manager objects controlling the lifecycle of their minions. Various objects dispatch and receive events; some events come from Windows, some are home-grown.

In general, we have to be very aware of thread interoperability so we use hand-rolled synchronization techniques using Win32 critical sections, semaphores and the like. However, occasionally we suffer thread deadlock during shut-down due to things like event handler re-entrancy.

Now I wonder if there is a decent app shut-down strategy we could implement to make this easier to develop for - something like every object registering for a shutdown event from a central controller and changing its execution behaviour accordingly? Is this too naive or brittle?

I would prefer strategies that don't stipulate rewriting the entire app to use Microsoft's Parallel Patterns Library or similar. ;-)

Thanks.

EDIT:

I guess I am asking for an approach to controlling object life cycles in a complex app where many threads and events are firing all the time. Giovanni's suggestion is the obvious one (hand-roll our own), but I am convinced there must be various off-the-shelf strategies or frameworks, for cleanly shutting down active objects in the correct order.  For example, if you want to base your C++ app on an IoC paradigm you might use PocoCapsule instead of trying to develop your own container. Is there something similar for controlling object lifecycles in an app?

Comment: Why are event handlers (used)/(especially problematic) at shutdown (and not at other times)?

Comment: I just tried to write an answer, but I realised that this question is unanswerable in its current form because it is too vague. If you are getting deadlocks then this is not a design issue but an implementation issue (of course your current design may make a correct implementation impossible). Any design which fixes the deadlocks would be an improvement.

Comment: @mankarse Because our shutdown strategy isn't robust enough in places to prevent deadlocks midway through events being dispatched and handled. Those are simply bugs of course and, when found, are fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible general strategy would be to send an "I am shutting down" event to every manager, which would cause the managers to do one of three things (depending on how long running your event-handlers are, and how much latency you want between the user initiating shutdown, and the app actually exiting).

> 1) Stop accepting new events, and run the handlers for all events received before the "I am shutting down" event. To avoid deadlocks you may need to accept events that are critical to the completion of other event handlers. These could be signaled by a flag in the event or the type of the event (for example). If you have such events then you should also consider restructuring your code so that those actions are not performed through event handlers (as dependent events would be prone to deadlocks in ordinary operation too.)
>
> 2) Stop accepting new events, and discard all events that were received after the event that the handler is currently running. Similar comments about dependent events apply in this case too.
>
> 3) Interrupt the currently running event (with a function similar to `boost::thread::interrupt()`), and run no further events. This requires your handler code to be exception safe (which it should already be, if you care about resource leaks), and to enter interruption points at fairly regular intervals, but it leads to the minimum latency.

Of course you could mix these three strategies together, depending on the particular latency and data corruption requirements of each of your managers.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a special case of the more general question, "how do I avoid deadlocks in my multithreaded application?"

And the answer to that is, as always: make sure that any time your threads have to acquire more than one lock at a time, that they all acquire the locks in the same order, and make sure all threads release their locks in a finite amount of time.  This rule applies just as much at shutdown as at any other time.  Nothing less is good enough; nothing more is necessary.  (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012640/locking-strategies-and-techniques-for-preventing-deadlocks-in-code/6012724#comment-6949643) for a relevant discussion)

As for how to best do this... the best way (if possible) is to simplify your program as much as you can, and avoid holding more than one lock at a time if you can possibly help it.

If you absolutely *must* hold more than one lock at a time, you must verify your program to be sure that every thread that holds multiple locks locks them in the same order.  Programs like [helgrind or Intel thread checker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114608/helgrind-for-windows) can help with this, but it often comes down to simply eyeballing the code until you've proved to yourself that it satisfies this constraint.  Also, if you are able to reproduce the deadlocks easily, you can examine (using a debugger) the stack trace of each deadlocked thread, which will show where the deadlocked threads are forever-blocked at, and with that information, you can that start to figure out where the lock-ordering inconsistencies are in your code.  Yes, it's a major pain, but I don't think there is any good way around it (other than avoiding holding multiple locks at once).  :(

Answer (score 1):

As a general method, use an atomic boolean to indicate "i am shutting down", then every thread checks this boolean before acquiring each lock, handling each event etc. Can't give a more detailed answer unless you give us a more detailed question.